# Download a region as KML/OSM from internet Maps

Tags: openstreetmap, kml, export, maps

I need to create a custom Euro Region map from several regions of neighborhood countries.

Say Spanish "Galicia" and Portugal "Norte" regions. So, I need to combine 2 KML/OSM/... files. My question is how to get that 2 files. Can I use the `openstreetmap` project to **EXPORT** desired regions **as KML**, by eg?

If not openstreet map, maybe google earth/maps, bing or other tools are available to export a desired region as KML?

**PS.** I don't mind using any of mapping formats like GeoJSON or OSM, KML was just an example

Comment: For Spain you can use the WFS Services of the IGN

Comment: I gave Span as example, but in reality is not Span my country ;) Thanks however

Comment: Dont you just love it when several people answer a question but dont upvote it...(+1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to get boundaries of countries, provinces and regions is to use the OSM Boundaries application:

https://osm.wno-edv-service.de/boundaries/

Extracting boundaries from generic tools like Overpass Turbo is not always easy, as the boundaries may contain errors and are likely complex multipolygons consisting of many parts.

The OSM Boundaries application seems to deal very well with most of these issues, and supplies you with completely resolved boundary polygons for many administrative levels in OSM.

Comment: I observed several errors when exporting some regions and them inporting them in umap of the openstreet maps. But the tool is extremly useful and practical, thanks a lot

Comment: What errors? And did you get the errors when downloading from OSM Boundaries, or importing in uMap? I am not familiar with uMap, and don't know if it can handle the type of very complex and large polygons that OSM boundaries may represent. You may need to simplify / generalize the boundaries first, before importing in uMap.

Comment: Url is outdated, page moved to https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get OpenStreetMap extracts would probably be through Mapzen's Metro Extracts tool [here](https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts/)

I would suggest exporting it in GeoJSON, then using a tool like ogr2gre (there's an online version [here](https://ogre.adc4gis.com/)) to convert it to KML.

You may also be interested in looking at [Overpass Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) for exporting data from OpenStreetMap.

Answer (score 2):

- Download administrative boundaries of the spain and portugal from in .shp format from http://www.gadm.org/
- you can import the shapefiles into QGIS or another software
- the filter with query builder to isolate the regions you are interested
- in QGIS you can install openlayer plugin
- from the vectors tab select- openstreetmap then select download data
- points, lines and polygons of the selected region will be downloaded in OSM
- Import OSM into QGIS and save as Shp or export as kml

Answer (score 1):

You could download data directly from [Openstreetmap](https://www.openstreetmap.org) as .osm file, and convert it in QGIS as .kml, since QGIS supports export data as .kml.

Alternatively, you could download data from [Geofabrik](https://www.geofabrik.de/data/download.html) (also openstreeet map data, but country by country, as .gbd/mdb, and in ArcMap, export it as .kml.

Also, I would suggest you to use, if you have, shapefiles od Spain and Portugal, which contain data about regions, so you could clip your data to selected regions, because no matter which source you use, you will need to edit data to fit you regions.

Comment: how can I download it from openstreetmap? I didn't find such an option

Comment: they have export button, but this does not work....

Comment: There is an export button on the upper side. But, i this those regions are too big to export. On the left down side, you can see other options to download. Also, on this question here, you could find other good answers. Also, other part of my answer, still stands, no matter where you download your data